# Error while establishing connection of on prem sql server to the azure data factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I created a self hosted integration runtime which runs on my machine perfectly. I then created a copy activity. I created a dataset for it which required a linked service. I entered all my credentials but once I do the 'Test Connection', got the below error:

```
'Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: 'DESKTOP-OERQNAM', Database: 'AdventureWorksLT2017', User: 'Crow'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
Login failed for user 'Crow'.,  Activity ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

[image].'[image]

Comment: Hey, Can you confirm whether the you are able to access the Azure SQL database from the server on which you have installed the SHIR? either via SSMS or powerbi etc

Comment: Yup, I'm able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to connect the on-premises SQL server linked service in my environment I got the similar error:

[image]

As per this [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) below are the possible solutions to resolve the issue:

1. Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 will allowed by your network's firewall.
2. Add the IP address of the self-hosted integration runtime machine to the list of allowed IP addresses.

It tested successfully after following above steps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I tried to on prem SQL server. Below are the steps I followed to resolve the issue.

Once the user is created using the query you mentioned in the first screenshot.

1. Right click the server and select properies
   [image: properies]
2. Under Security select 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication' and click ok.
   [image: Security settings]
3. Now, in the Azure Linked Service, select the Authentication type as 'SQL Authentication' and provide the username and password and click 'Test connect'. You should be able to connect.
   [image: Linked Service]